# Redirect from one domain to another and add .html at new url end

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all pages from one domain to another and I have tried following directives

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.guru99.com/$1.html [R=301,L]
```

but it's getting redirected to wrong url like

```
webtest.guru99.com to
http://test.guru99.com/.html
```

and

```
webtest.guru99.com/php-tutorials/ to
test.guru99.com/php-tutorials/.html
```

Now, I want to suppress this / at the end of url, It should be redirected with or without / at the end of the url.

Please help me to sort this out.

Regards

Comment: yes, and It should work with or without / at the end of old domain url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid empty matches in your regex.

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ http://test.guru99.com/$1.html [R=301,L]
```

#### UPDATE:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-contents/uploads/(.+?\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif|tiff))$ http://test.guru99.com/images/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. if url contains /wp-contents/uploads/ then it should replaced with /images/ like,

webtest.guru99.com/wp-contents/uploads/2013/xyz.png  to 
test.guru99.com/images/2013/xyz.png 

is this possible with .htaccess, how i can do this?, as i have many urls like this in my site

Comment: it's getting redirected but after /images/, it also includes wp-contents/uploads which i don't want to include. I want target url like this test.guru99.com/images/2013/xyz.png

but here i'm getting this http://test.guru99.com/images/wp-contents/uploads/2013/xyz.png

Comment: You need to place that rule in different `/wp-contents/uploads/.htaccess` file not in same .htaccess

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)/wp-contents/uploads/(.*)$ $1/images/$2 [R=301,L]

I want to do this from root .htaccess, can i use this code?

Comment: Avoid doing it from root as `/wp-contents/uploads/.htaccess` might already be there and that will block your rules in root .htaccess rule. Can you check if `/wp-contents/uploads/.htaccess` OR `/wp-contents/.htaccess` already exist?

Comment: No there is no .htaccess file in /wp-contents/ or in /wp-contents/uploads/